# Has anyone managed to run Raspberry Pi 3 with KVM enabled?

Tags: qemu, virtualization

I have seen some tutorials for Raspberry pi 2, but they are either a bit old, or do not work on the 3 model. I would like basically to run QEMU with KVM, for a x86 guest, in order for it to perform at a satisfactory level, right now it is very slow. The big picture is to run as a nova compute node for openstack. But for now the simple virtualization is a step.

Comment: the Pi is not powerful enough for virtualisation

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but:

You won't be able to use **KVM** to run an x86 guest on the Raspberry Pi (any version), as the Raspberry Pi uses an ARM CPU core.  Now, this doesn't mean that you can't run an x86 guest at all, but performance will be quite slow.  (The link above is likely about using KVM to run an ARM guest, not an x86 guest).

Before the KVM extensions, QEMU was essentially an "emulator" - not virtualization.  KVM allows a certain level of "passthrough" of operations from the guest CPU to the host CPU - that's what defines it as "virtualization" rather than emulation.  (One main reason that VMWare became king in this arena is that they were able to perform that type of "virtualization" before the x86 CPUs had added the virtualization extensions to the architecture. Those same virtualization extensions are what is required to run KVM, or in fact any modern **virtualization** hypervisor, as opposed to **emulation**).

So, it's theoretically possible to run x86 "Virtual machines" on a Raspberry Pi, but performance will be *very* slow, as every x86 instruction has to be translated / emulated by the ARM CPU on the Pi.  Per [this project](https://github.com/mikerr/RPi-QEMU-x86-wine) dedicated to running Wine with a QEMU x86 execution layer, you can expect performance on par with a "300mhz Pentium"  (Presumably they mean a Pentium II, or such).  Depending on what tasks you want to be doing, you may not find this performance adequate.  If you're looking to run a Windows application, the Wine/QEMU option is almost certainly a better option than fully emulating a Windows environment with QEMU.

Answer (score 2):

## Linux Containers

Another container technology which can also run on SBCs is Linux Containers (LXC/LXD). LXC shares the host's kernel and is lighter weight than traditional Virtual Machines. But each LXC Container is isolated via namespaces and control groups, so it appears to have its own network stack. And therefore is more flexible than Docker.

#### What is the difference LXC vs LXD

In this article I will treat LXC and LXD as LXC, but they are separate. LXC (or Linux Containers) existed first. Versions 1 & 2 created Virtual Machines. With version 3, LXD was added, which provides a daemon that allows easier image management, including publishing images and an API to control LXC on remote machines. LXD complements LXC by providing more features.

Is LXD and LXD-Client in the repo (easy to install with apt-get)
Does the kernel support namespaces
The first is easy, search for the packages:

```
$ apt-cache search lxd-client
lxd-client - Container hypervisor based on LXC - client
The second involves what support was compiled into the kernel when it was built. Namespaces allow the kernel to create separate network areas, each with its own firewall rules. The easiest way to determine this is to look for namespace items in /proc

$ ls /proc/self/ns
ipc  mnt  net  pid  user  uts
```

Unfortunately, the raspian kernel from raspberrypi.org doesn't support namespaces.

#### Getting a LXC/LXD compatible OS

UPDATE: Sept 2019: Raspian Buster now supports Linux Containers (LXD) by using snapd. To install LXD on Raspian:

```
sudo apt-get install snapd  bridge-utils
sudo snap install core lxd
Add your userid to the lxd group, and run lxd init. Done!
```

Fortunately, there is an unofficial Ubuntu 18.04 image available for the Pi which does. This image is compressed and must be decompressed before flashed to a SD Card. Fortunately in Linux you can do this on the fly:

```
$ xzcat ubuntu-18.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz | sudo dd  of=/dev/sdZ bs=100M
Change sdZ to the device of your SD Card. Be careful with this command, if you give it the device of your boot drive, it will happily overwrite your boot device.
```

If you are using Window or a Mac, I suggest using Etcher which makes creating bootable SD Cards easy.

Make sure you follow the steps on the Ubuntu page to set an initial password for the ubuntu user. Best Practices is to setup a non-privileged user which you will use most of the time. This can be done with the adduser command. Below I have created a user craig with sudo privilages:

```
$ sudo adduser --ingroup sudo craig
Adding user `craig' ...
Adding new user `craig' (1002) with group `sudo' ...
Creating home directory `/home/craig' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for craig
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: Craig Miller
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n] y
```

Additionally follow the steps to boot the unofficial image on the Raspberry 3B+. Be sure to update the config.txt file and update the bootloader files. The Raspsberry 3B can boot the unofficial image without these extra steps.

#### Preparing the LXC Host (aka the Pi)

The key networking difference between Docker and LXC is that with LXC one can attach a container to any bridge on the Host. This includes a bridge on the outside interface. Via transparent bridging the container can have unfettered access to the existing IPv6 subnet, including picking up Global Unique Addresses (GUAs) without the host having to do router-like functions, such as adding routes, auto propagation of prefixes (with DHCPv6-PD), redistribution of routes, etc. Again, things which Docker doesn't support.

#### Setting up an external bridge interface on the Host

Once you have the right kernel and distro, configure a bridge br0 which will in-turn have the ethernet interface as a member. This is best done from the Pi itself using a keyboard and monitor, rather than ssh-ing to a headless device. Because when you mess up, you are still connected to the Pi (believe me, it is easy to get disconnected with all interfaces down). Logically the bridge, br0 will not only be attached to the eth0 interface, but later on, the LXC Containers as well.

#### Set up the bridge

Install brctl the utility which controls/creates linux bridges. And install the ifupdown package which will be used later.
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils ifupdown
Edit the /etc/network/interfaces file to automatically set up the bridge br0 and attach the ethernet device. Add the following lines:

```
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
iface br0 inet6 dhcp
```

Because Ubuntu uses systemd we must let systemd know about the bridge, or the IPv6 default route will disappear after about 5 minutes (not good).

Create/Edit /etc/systemd/network/br0.network file, and add the following:
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
Lastly, in order to make this all work when the Pi is rebooted, we have to hack at /etc/rc.local a bit to make sure the bridge is brought up and systemd is minding it at boot up time.

Create/Edit /etc/rc.local and add the following, and don't forget to make it executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
## put hacks here

# fix for br0 interface
/sbin/ifup br0
# kick networkd as well
/bin/systemctl restart systemd-networkd
echo "Bridge is up"
exit 0
```

Make it executable:

```
$ sudo chmod 754 /etc/rc.local
```

Finally, reboot, login and see that the Pi br0 network is up

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:6c:02:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:6c:02:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.215.141/24 brd 192.168.215.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 1995525700sec preferred_lft 1995525700sec
    inet6 2001:db8:ebbd:2080::9c5/128 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:db8:ebbd:2080:ba27:ebff:fe6c:288/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe6c:288/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you can see, br0 has all the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses which is what we want. Now you can go back to headless access (via ssh) if you are like me, and the Pi is just sitting on a shelf.

## Installing LXC/LXD

Once setting up the br0 interface is done, we can install lxd and lxd-client. Linux Containers has been evolving of the years, and it is now (as I write this) up to version 3.0.2.

### Doing the install

Installing LXD will pull in lxc as well. And because we are using Ubuntu 18.04LTS, it is as simple as using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install lxd lxd-client
But wait! It is already installed on this image. Although it is version 3.0.0, and the easiest way to get it to the latest version is to run:

$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade lxd lxd-client
Add yourself to the lxd group so you won't have to type sudo all the time.

sudo usermod -aG lxd craig
newgrp lxd
LXD Init
The LXD init script sets up LXD on the machine with a set of interactive questions. It is safe to accept all the defaults (just press return):

$ sudo lxd init
Would you like to use LXD clustering? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Do you want to configure a new storage pool? (yes/no) [default=yes]: 
Name of the new storage pool [default=default]: 
Name of the storage backend to use (btrfs, dir, lvm) [default=btrfs]: 
Create a new BTRFS pool? (yes/no) [default=yes]: 
Would you like to use an existing block device? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Size in GB of the new loop device (1GB minimum) [default=15GB]: 
Would you like to connect to a MAAS server? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Would you like to create a new network bridge? (yes/no) [default=yes]: 
What should the new bridge be called? [default=lxdbr0]: 
What IPv4 address should be used? (CIDR subnet notation, "auto" or "none") [default=auto]: 
What IPv6 address should be used? (CIDR subnet notation, "auto" or "none") [default=auto]: 
Would you like LXD to be available over the network? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Would you like stale cached images to be updated automatically? (yes/no) [default=yes] no
Would you like a YAML "lxd init" preseed to be printed? (yes/no) [default=no]: yes
```

If you answer yes to the last question, you will see the output of all those questions in YAML (Yet Another Markup Language) format.

```
config:
  images.auto_update_interval: "0"
cluster: null
networks:
- config:
    ipv4.address: auto
    ipv6.address: auto
  description: ""
  managed: false
  name: lxdbr0
  type: ""
storage_pools:
- config:
    size: 15GB
  description: ""
  name: default
  driver: btrfs
profiles:
- config: {}
  description: ""
  devices:
    eth0:
      name: eth0
      nictype: bridged
      parent: lxdbr0
      type: nic
    root:
      path: /
      pool: default
      type: disk
  name: default
```

On the Pi, LXD will take a while to think about all this, just be patient (might be 10 minutes or so).

## Default LXD Networking

Since we took all the defaults of lxd init it created another bridge on the system lxdbr0 which the YAML file would lead you to believe it is also bridged to the outside world, but it is not. The default config is similar to Docker, in that it creates a lxdbr0 bridge which uses NAT4 and NAT6 to connect to the outside world.

But we don't care, because we have created a bridge br0 which is transparently bridged to the outside world. And unlike Docker, individual containers can be attached to any bridge (either br0 or if you want NAT, lxdbr0)

Create a profile for the external transparent bridge (br0)
There is one more thing we have to do before running the first Linux Container, create a profile for the br0 bridge. Edit the profile to match the info below:

```
lxc profile create extbridge
lxc profile edit extbridge
    config: {}
    description: bridged networking LXD profile
    devices:
      eth0:
        name: eth0
        nictype: bridged
        parent: br0
        type: nic
    name: extbridge
    used_by:
```

Note: if you prefer vi to whatever editor comes up when editing the profile, set the environment variable below, then edit the profile.

```
export EDITOR=vi
```

The Linux Container network is now ready to attach containers to the br0 bridge like this:
You may notice the bottom LXC container with Docker, more on this later.

Running the first Linux Container
So now it is time to have fun by running the first container. I suggest Alpine Linux because it is small, and quick to load. To create and start the container type the following:

```
lxc launch -p default -p extbridge images:alpine/3.8 alpine
```

LXD will automatically download the Alpine Linux image from the Linux Containers image server, and create a container with the name alpine. We'll use the name alpine to manage the container going forward.

Typing lxc ls will list the running containers

```
$ lxc ls
+---------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
|  NAME   |  STATE  |          IPV4          |                     IPV6                     |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+---------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| alpine  | RUNNING | 192.168.215.104 (eth0) | fd6a:c19d:b07:2080:216:3eff:fecf:bef5 (eth0) | PERSISTENT | 0         |
|         |         |                        | 2001:db8:ebbd:2080:216:3eff:fecf:bef5 (eth0) |            |           |
+---------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
```

You will note that the container has not only a IPv4 address from my DHCP server, but it also has an IPv6 GUA (and in this case, an additional IPv6 ULA, Unique Local Address).

#### YAML overlaying

The alpine container has a GUA because we used two -p (profile) parameters when creating it. The first is the default profile which as I mentioned earlier is set up for NAT4 and NAT6. And the second is the extbridge profile we setup as a profile. The lxc launch command pulls in the YAML info from the default profile, and then overlays the extbridge profile, effectively overwriting the parts we want so that the alpine container is attached to br0 and the outside world!

#### Stepping into Alpine

Of course, what good is starting a Linux Container if all you can do is start and stop it. A key difference from Docker is that Linux Containers are not read-only, but rather you can install software, configure it the way you like, and then stop the container. When you start it again, all the changes you made are still there. I'll talk about the goodness of this a little later.

But in order to do that customization one needs to get inside the container. This is done with the following command:

```
$ lxc exec alpine -- /bin/sh
~ #
```

And now you are inside the running container as root. Here you can do anything you can do on a normal linux machine, install software, add users, start sshd, so you can ssh to it later, and so on. When you are done customizing the container type:

```
~ # exit
craig@pai:~$
```

And you are back on the LXC Host.

#### Advantages of customizing a container

A key advantage of customizing a container, is that you can create a template which then can be used to crate many instances of that customized application. For example, I started with alpine installed nginx and php7 and created a template image, which I called web_image. I used the following commands on the host, after installing the webserver with PHP inside the container:

```
$ lxc snapshot alpine snapshot_web                   # Make a back up of the container
$ lxc publish alpine/snapshot_web --alias web_image  # publish the back up as an image
$ lxc image list                                     # show the list of images
+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
|    ALIAS     | FINGERPRINT  | PUBLIC |             DESCRIPTION              |  ARCH  |   SIZE   |         UPLOAD DATE         |
+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
| web_image    | 84a4b1f466ad | no     |                                      | armv7l | 12.86MB  | Dec 4, 2018 at 2:46am (UTC) |
+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
|              | 49b522955166 | no     | Alpine 3.8 armhf (20181203_13:03)    | armv7l | 2.26MB   | Dec 3, 2018 at 5:11pm (UTC) |
+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

#### Scaling up the template container

And with that webserver image, I can replicate it as many times as I have disk space and memory. I tried 10, but based on how much memory it was using, I think I could have gone to twenty on the Pi.

```
$ lxc ls
+--------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
|  NAME  |  STATE  |          IPV4          |                     IPV6                     |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+--------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| alpine | RUNNING | 192.168.215.104 (eth0) | fd6a:c19d:b07:2080:216:3eff:fecf:bef5 (eth0) | PERSISTENT | 0         |
|        |         |                        | 2001:db8:ebbd:2080:216:3eff:fecf:bef5 (eth0) |            |           |
+--------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| w10    | RUNNING | 192.168.215.225 (eth0) | fd6a:c19d:b07:2080:216:3eff:feb2:f03d (eth0) | PERSISTENT | 0         |
|        |         |                        | 2001:db8:ebbd:2080:216:3eff:feb2:f03d (eth0) |            |           |
+--------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| w2     | RUNNING | 192.168.215.232 (eth0) | fd6a:c19d:b07:2080:216:3eff:fe7f:b6a5 (eth0) | PERSISTENT | 0         |
|        |         |                        | 2001:db8:ebbd:2080:216:3eff:fe7f:b6a5 (eth0) |            |           |
+--------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| w3     | RUNNING | 192.168.215.208 (eth0) | fd6a:c19d:b07:2080:216:3eff:fe63:4544 (eth0) | PERSISTENT | 0         |
|        |         |                        | 2001:db8:ebbd:2080:216:3eff:fe63:4544 (eth0) |            |           |
+--------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| w4     | RUNNING | 192.168.215.244 (eth0) | fd6a:c19d:b07:2080:216:3eff:fe99:a784 (eth0) | PERSISTENT | 0         |
|        |         |                        | 2001:db8:ebbd:2080:216:3eff:fe99:a784 (eth0) |            |           |
+--------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| w5     | RUNNING | 192.168.215.118 (eth0) | fd6a:c19d:b07:2080:216:3eff:fe31:690e (eth0) | PERSISTENT | 0         |
|        |         |                        | 2001:db8:ebbd:2080:216:3eff:fe31:690e (eth0) |            |           |
+--------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| w6     | RUNNING | 192.168.215.200 (eth0) | fd6a:c19d:b07:2080:216:3eff:fee2:8fc7 (eth0) | PERSISTENT | 0         |
|        |         |                        | 2001:db8:ebbd:2080:216:3eff:fee2:8fc7 (eth0) |            |           |
+--------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| w7     | RUNNING | 192.168.215.105 (eth0) | fd6a:c19d:b07:2080:216:3eff:feec:baf7 (eth0) | PERSISTENT | 0         |
|        |         |                        | 2001:db8:ebbd:2080:216:3eff:feec:baf7 (eth0) |            |           |
+--------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| w8     | RUNNING | 192.168.215.196 (eth0) | fd6a:c19d:b07:2080:216:3eff:fe90:10b2 (eth0) | PERSISTENT | 0         |
|        |         |                        | 2001:db8:ebbd:2080:216:3eff:fe90:10b2 (eth0) |            |           |
+--------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| w9     | RUNNING | 192.168.215.148 (eth0) | fd6a:c19d:b07:2080:216:3eff:fee3:e5b2 (eth0) | PERSISTENT | 0         |
|        |         |                        | 2001:db8:ebbd:2080:216:3eff:fee3:e5b2 (eth0) |            |           |
+--------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| web    | RUNNING | 192.168.215.110 (eth0) | fd6a:c19d:b07:2080:216:3eff:fe29:7f8 (eth0)  | PERSISTENT | 1         |
|        |         |                        | 2001:db8:ebbd:2080:216:3eff:fe29:7f8 (eth0)  |            |           |
+--------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
```

All of the webservers have their own unique IPv6 address, and all of them are running on port 80, something that can't be done using NAT.

After creating two, I wrote a little shell script to create the rest, called [start_webs.sh]

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {3..10}
do
  echo "starting web container: $i"
  # check free memory
  free -h
  lxc launch -p default -p extbridge local:web_image w$i
done
# show the containers
lxc ls
```

#### LXC plays well with DNS

Unlike Docker, LXC containers retain the same IPv6 address after being start and stopped. And if you are starting multiple containers, the order of starting doesn't change the address (as Docker does).

This means that you can assign names to your LXC Containers without a lot of DNS churn. Here's a chunk from my DNS zone file:
After getting it started, it is easy to step into the LXC container docker1 and query Docker on its container:

```
lxc exec docker1 -- /bin/bash
root@docker1:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
19f3cbeba6d3        linuxserver/nginx   "/init"             3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   nginx
root@docker1:~#
```

#### Running multiple LXC + Docker containers

Now that there is a template image, docker_image it is a breeze to spawn multiple LXC + Docker Containers. Don't want them all to run nginx webservers? Easy, step into each, delete the nginx webserver and run of of the other thousands of Docker Containers.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. But, you can do it yourself. [(link)](http://blog.flexvdi.com/2015/03/17/enabling-kvm-virtualization-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/)

But, the interesting thing here is [there's no difference between the Pi2 and the Pi3 kernel](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=138519) (yet). So, go use a KVM-enabled Pi2 kernel. Good luck with performance though.

Answer (score 1):

Given the similarity in kernels between the 2 and 3, this tutorial might provide some guidance.

https://blog.flexvdi.com/2015/03/17/enabling-kvm-virtualization-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/

The context is CentOS running on top of KVM, but the author has done a detailed job of describing the steps to getting the Pi ready for virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer says, it's not possible to run KVM for x86 images running on arm.

But, if you want to try KVM on the RPi 3, the easiest way that I found is using ArchLinux: https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3.

Install qemu with pacman: `pacman -S qemu` and if wanted `pacman -S qemu-arch-extras`. The version is quite new:

```
# qemu-system-aarch64 --version
QEMU emulator version 2.11.0
Copyright (c) 2003-2017 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

With that OS installed, you have kvm enabled.

```
# dmesg | grep kvm
[    0.632551] kvm [1]: 8-bit VMID
[    0.636143] kvm [1]: IDMAP page: 1c7d000
[    0.639532] kvm [1]: HYP VA range: 800000000000:ffffffffffff
[    0.644281] kvm [1]: Invalid trigger for IRQ4, assuming level low
[    0.647576] kvm [1]: virtual timer IRQ4
[    0.650829] kvm [1]: Hyp mode initialized successfully
```

And to run for example CirrOS, I used the following guide: https://www.cnx-software.com/2016/05/10/how-to-run-ubuntu-16-04-aarch64-64-bit-arm-cloud-images-on-your-intelamd-linux-computer/. In short:

```
curl http://download.cirros-cloud.net/0.4.0/cirros-0.4.0-aarch64-disk.img --output cirros-0.4.0-aarch64-disk.img
curl https://releases.linaro.org/components/kernel/uefi-linaro/15.12/release/qemu64/QEMU_EFI.fd --output QEMU_EFI.fd
```

Then I create the `cloud.img` in my x86_64 (Ubuntu) machine with cloud-utils (skipped, check reference).

And execute in the RPI with the following:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -smp 2 -m 300 -M virt -bios QEMU_EFI.fd -nographic \
-device virtio-blk-device,drive=image \
-drive if=none,id=image,file=cirros-0.4.0-aarch64-disk.img \
-device virtio-blk-device,drive=cloud \
-drive if=none,id=cloud,file=cloud.img \
-netdev user,id=user0 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=user0 -redir tcp:2222::22 \
-cpu host --enable-kvm
```

It should fly!

Answer (score -1):

If a linux guest is enough for you -- go on with the LXD/LXC.
Snap install is the solution here. You can even run a VirtualBox on top if it ;)
Some more details on networking setup of Pi host:
http://www.makikiweb.com/Pi/lxc_on_the_pi.html

Comment: Nothing will remain of this answer once the link is gone. Could you please add the relevant content in this post?